# Problem with Runtime

Tags: java, runtime.exec

How to make this work on windows , the file filename.txt is not being created.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd echo name > filename.txt");
```

Clearly the expected output is a "filename.txt" should be created (C:\Documents and Settings\username\filename.txt )  with the content  "name".

---

Was able to manage with the following code , even though the file was"filename.txt" is not being created with processBuilder

```
       Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process process = runtime.exec("cmd /c cleartool lsview");
       // Directly to file

//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( 
//              new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "cleartool lsview > filename.txt" },null, new File("C:/Documents and Settings/username/")); 

       InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String line;

       System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
           Arrays.toString(args));

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }
```

OR , using ProceessBuilder ,

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd", "/c", "cleartool lsview" ).start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: how it doesn't work now?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Clearly? are you running it straight from `C:\Documents and Settings\username\` folder?

Comment: why are you actually trying to use cmd for that? Can't you do it with `java.io.File`?

Comment: The command you're executing opens a command window on my machine. Do you mean `cmd /k echo name > filename.txt`?

Comment: My actual need is "cmd cleartool lsview > views.txt" , the one i gave in the above example is for ease of understanding

Comment: @srinannapa Did you execute that command? As far as I understand cmd, it will NOT run 'cleartool lsview > views.txt' if you start cmd like that. Does running it via Start -> Run produce the expected result?

Comment: Yes i am able execute with plain command prompt. I would like to achieve the same with java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should actually be using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec` (see [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29)).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("your_command", "arg1", "arg2");
pb.directory(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/username/"));

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt");
InputStream in = pb.start().getInputStream();

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
    out.write(buf, 0, len);

out.close();
```

(I'd adapt it to cmd and echo if I had a windows-machine in reach... Feel free to edit this post!)

Comment: Bear in mind that `ProcessBuilder` was introduced in JDK 5. Earlier version of the JDK will still require `Runtime.exec(...)`.

Comment: The root of the problem (passing a single string which is splitted at the wrong places) stays the same whether you use `ProcessBuilder` or `exec()`.

Comment: My actual need is "cmd cleartool lsview > views.txt"  , the execpect output from the command cleartool lsview  should goto views.txt file. This is working fine with normal cmd prompt. But within the java program i did like to achieve this

Comment: @musiKk; You're right. I could clarify that `your_command` probably corresponds to `cmd` and `arg1` to `echo name`. However, I don't have a windows-machine available to test this. (That's why I said that everybody are free to edit the post.)

Comment: @srinannapa, the try to do `new ProcessBuilder("cleartool", "lsview");` in the above solution.

Comment: @StackTrace : if we execute through start->run->cmd-> we just need cleartool lsview > views.txt

Comment: @srinannapa, you could also try to put the full path to cleartool as the first argument to the ProcessBuilder constructor.

Comment: Yes, fullpath is not required becuase i have cleartool in path environment variable. Please check the question update with

Comment: @srinannapa, looks good! The ProcessBuilder solution looks better imo ;)

Answer (score 4):

It should work with

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "echo name > filename.txt" });
```

I don't have Windows running at the moment so unfortunately I can't test it.

The reason behind this is that in your version, the command gets splitted at every space character. So what the runtime does is create a process `cmd` and feed it the arguments `echo`, `name`, `>` and `filename.txt` which makes no sense. The command `echo name > filename.txt` is a single argument to the `cmd` process and so you have to provide an array with the different arguments manually.

If you want to make sure that the file is created in a particular folder you have to provide a working directory to `exec()` which only works in the three argument version:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "echo name > filename.txt" },
    null, new File("C:/Documents and Settings/username/"));
```

Comment: Platform dependent solution though.

Comment: it's a platform-dependent question anyway :)

Comment: Yes Bozho. I don't really get that comment. If you exec something it is (almost?) always platform dependent.

Comment: Will this work? I didn't think `Runtime.exec` could handle the redirection in `echo name > filename.txt`

Comment: @tim: That's why it's an argument to `cmd` which handles redirection. Not `exec()`.